# How to correctly plug CSS into HTML with absolute path to make picture from CSS working?

Tags: html, css, webstorm, relative-path, absolute-path

It might sound silly, but I am trying to understand this.

When I plugged CSS with absolute path - picture/fonts are not loading (404).

I test a page on the built-in WebStorm server (2022.3) through Chrome browser.

<sub>[i just heard absolute paths are better, that is why]</sub>

What did I miss?

Here is an example:

<kbd>file structure</kbd>

```
css-pract[root]/
-folder/
--css/
---styles.css
--img/
---some.jpg
-index.html
```

<kbd>index.html</kbd>

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/folder/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="has-bg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

<kbd>styles.css</kbd>

```css
.has-bg {
  background: url("/folder/img/some.jpg");
}
```

It works when I do relative: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`

Also, the `<img>` from `index.html` are loaded with absolute paths, so I was expecting it to work from css also.

Comment: *"I test a page on the built-in WebStorm server"* Check what URL is uses. It will be something like `localhost:63345/PROJECT_NAME/the/path/to/file`. The `PROJECT_NAME` part here is required and this what would be breaking the stuff as the proper *full* path should really be something like `/PROJECT_NAME/folder/css/styles.css` etc.

Comment: *"When I plugged CSS with absolute path - picture/fonts are not loading (404)."* Considering the above -- open your browser's "Dev Tools | Network tab", request a page and check the actual URLs that got requested (the 404 ones). Alter then URL using the above info and see if it will make it work.

Comment: That 'folder/' i wrote - it is the PROJECT_NAME you talking about, so, that is not what breaking stuff. Thank you though, that is trivial example, but it shows the big gap in my knowledges .-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tied to replicate your folder structure and both relative and absolute paths worked for me.

You need to give the div with class "has-bg" a height, however, in order to see the background image. Perhaps you forgot to do this for the absolute paths?

**Relative paths**

in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./folder/css/styles.css" />
```

in styles.css:

```
background: url("../img/some.jpg");
```

**Absolute paths**

in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/folder/css/styles.css" />
```

in styles.css:

```
background: url("/folder/img/some.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `/folder/css/styles.css` also is kinda a relative path. If you are using Windows, some full absolute path should be something like: `C:/Folder/image.jpg`.

You're doing this just for studies purpose? If yes, I don't think you need to be worry about this.

If you're gonna deploy it in some server, then you gonna have a full absolute path looking something like: `https://website.com/images/image.jpg` and then you can correctly use the absolute path as something like `BASE_PATH/image/image.jpg` where `BASE_PATH` is some variable with the full website link.

Comment: Thank you, i can not rate your answer yet, but it is useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to set the base in the `<head>` of your html like this

```
<base href="https://www.example.com/">
```

Then all relative url's in your page will be preceded with this url.

```
folder/img/some.jpg
```

will become

```
https://www.example.com/folder/img/some.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, that answer is great addition to all above!